# A PHP Error using Champagne 2 Module

Tags: add-on, module, php

I have loaded the Champagne 2 (Mighty Big Robot - no support) Module to EE and when I try and use it I just get a bunch of PHP errors listed below. Looks like it might be some sort of conflict.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

David

Other info:

- PHP Version 5.2.6
- Apache 2.0
- MySQL 5.0.77
- EE 2.5.3

Other add-ons (all up to date):

- Freeform
- Matrix
- Mountee
- Playa
- Video player
- Wygwam
- Zenbu
- devotee monitor

Error messages:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Constant SERVICES_JSON_SLICE already defined
Filename: class/services_json.php
Line Number: 61
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Constant SERVICES_JSON_IN_STR already defined
Filename: class/services_json.php
Line Number: 66
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Constant SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR already defined
Filename: class/services_json.php
Line Number: 71
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Constant SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ already defined
Filename: class/services_json.php
Line Number: 76
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Constant SERVICES_JSON_IN_CMT already defined
Filename: class/services_json.php
Line Number: 81
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Constant SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE already defined
Filename: class/services_json.php
Line Number: 86

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Services_JSON in /expressionengine/third_party/champagne/lib/cm_v3_api/class/services_json.php on line 115
```

Comment: Please post line 115 from the services_json.php file to your question.

Comment: Champagne is loading the `Services_JSON` class which they have bundled, without checking whether it is already loaded. Another add-on must also be loading this class as well. MBR will need to fix this so you should email them if you have not already.